# table main_about has no column named featured_image

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am getting an error saying `table main_about has no column named featured_image`. I've tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` however it is not working. The only thing I can think to do is delete the database but I'm hoping to avoid doing that. I read you can manually add columns through the shell?

**views.py**

```
def about_view(request):
    context = {
        "about": About.objects.first(),
    }
    return render(request, "main/about.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
class About(models.Model):
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="about")
    about_text = models.TextField()

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="height: 150; width: auto;"/>' % (self.featured_image.url))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "About Page"

    def __str__(self):
        return "About Page"
```

Comment: Sometimes it problems when IDE holds on cash file. Restart your IDE or delete your previous migrations file. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you executed these commands after adding you model

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and if you still getting the same issue try to execute it like this

```
python manage.py makemigrations <yourapp>
```

hope this helps ^_^